# How do I replace row identifiers with sequential numbers?

Tags: perl, loops, split

I have written a perl script that splits 3 columns into scalars and replaces various values in the second column using regex. This part works fine, as shown below. What I would like to do, though, is change the first column ($item_id into a series of sequential numbers that restart when the original (numeric) value of $item_id changes.

For example:
123
123
123
123
2397
2397
2397
2397
8693
8693
8693
8693

would be changed to something like this (in a column):

1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4

This could either replace the first column or be a new fourth column.
I understand that I might do this through a series of if-else statements and tried this, but that doesn't seem to play well with the while procedure I've already got working for me. - Thanks, Thom Shepard

```
open(DATA,"< text_to_be_processed.txt");
while (<DATA>)
{
chomp;
my ($item_id,$callnum,$data)=split(/\|/);
$callnum=~s/110/\%I/g;
$callnum=~s/245/\%T/g;
$callnum=~s/260/\%U/g;
print "$item_id\t$callnum\t$data\n";
}   #End while
close DATA;
```

Comment: Note that [DATA is a predefined filehandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors).  You should be using [lexical filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps are:

Outside of the loop declare the counter and a variable holding the previous `$item_id`.

Inside the loop you do three things:

1. reset the counter to 1 if the current `$item_id` differs from the previous one, otherwise increase it
2. use that counter, e.g. print it
3. remember the previous value

With code this could look something similar to this (untested):

```
my ($counter, $prev_item_id) = (0, '');
while (<DATA>) {
  # do your thing
  $counter      = $item_id eq $prev_item_id ? $counter + 1 : 1;
  $prev_item_id = $item_id;
  print "$item_id\t$counter\t...\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mortiz, for your solution. If I don't use it for this particular problem, I will certainly file it away and use it for several others. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This goes a little further than just what you asked...

- Use [lexical filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- [autodie] makes open throw an error automatically
- Replace the call nums using a table
- Don't assume the data is sorted by item ID

Here's the code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open(my $fh, "<", "text_to_be_processed.txt");

my %Callnum_Map = (
    110         => '%I',
    245         => '%T',
    260         => '%U',
);

my %item_id_count;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my($item_id,$callnum,$data) = split m{\|};

    for my $search (keys %Callnum_Map) {
        my $replace = $Callnum_Map{$search};
        $callnum =~ s{$search}{$replace}g;
    }


    my $item_count = ++$item_id_count{$item_id};

    print "$item_id\t$callnum\t$data\t$item_count\n";
}
```

By using a hash, it does not presume the data is sorted by item ID.  So if it sees...

```
123|foo|bar
456|up|down
123|left|right
789|this|that
456|black|white
123|what|huh
```

It will produce...

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
```

This is more robust, assuming you want a count of how many times you've seen an item id in the whole file.  If you want how many times its been seen consecutively, use Mortiz's solution.

Comment: I tweaked this a little, dropping #use autodie; and it works flawlessly for me! Tudor Constantin and Moritz Bunkus also provided good solutions, but I will likely use the more robust solution that you provided. Thank you very much with my very first perl question!

Comment: @ThomasShepard Welcome on Stack Overflow! :) It is good practice here not only to upvote but to accept answers that work for you. Read more about this in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
open(DATA,"< text_to_be_processed.txt");
my $counter = 0;
my $prev;

while (<DATA>)
{
chomp;
my ($item_id,$callnum,$data)=split(/\|/);
$callnum=~s/110/\%I/g;
$callnum=~s/245/\%T/g;
$callnum=~s/260/\%U/g;
++$counter;
$item_id = $counter;
#reset counter if $prev is different than $item_id
$counter = 0 if ($prev ne $item_id );
$prev = $item_id;
print "$item_id\t$callnum\t$data\n";
}   #End while
close DATA;
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, once I fixed the typo ($previous -> $prev). It was the easiest solution to follow and to test. Thank you so much!